# jQuery width() is incorrect on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load my page and use `$('div.logo').width()` it returns a massive value of `6500`, which is incorrect. The image is only 130 px wide.

But, if I use a `setTimeout` and check the `$('div.logo').width()` after a few seconds it returns the correct width.

Why would this be? All of my CSS should be already loaded so why would the few second pause make a difference?

Comment: Its cause of when your code run, image is not loaded.

Comment: When are you checking the `width` using `$('.logo img').width()`? It is possible that the image is not loaded when you are checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the image width after the image has been loaded.

So either:

```
// NOTE: not $(document).ready
$(window).load(function() {
  var width = $('.logo img').width();
});
```

Or

```
$('.logo img').load(function() {
  var width = $(this).width();
});
```

should give the right width.

Comment: No, that isn't the issue. It happens with `$('.logo').width()` as well.

Comment: `.logo` is a div that has an image inside.

Comment: @NicHubbard So that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `width` and `height` attributes to the image. You can specify the size in CSS too. Then the browser will know what size the image will be before it loads.

Comment: `.width()` will get computed width, not the attribute width: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: @mikedidthis if you set the `width` attr of the `img` tag, then it is actually the `width` the `img` will have when it is displayed by the browser, so it IS the computed width. It is also good practice to set the `width` and `height` of the image so that the browser knows it before the image is loaded.

Comment: @t.niese that is true, but if the OP CSS sets `max-width: 100%` then the value isn't correct.

Comment: @mikedidthis if the OP set the css to `max-width: 100%`, the image has a width of `130px` and the container then has a width of `100px` the `$('div.logo').width()`  will return `100`. But this will happen in both cases (no matter if the `width` attr is set or not).

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification. I agreed its a good practice to set the `width` / `height` attributes. Example here if anyone is interested: http://jsbin.com/xasuf/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

That's because an image is not loaded yet, so initial size is based on CSS or guessed. You can use:

```
$('.logo img').load(function() {
  var width = $(this).width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Image is getting loaded with `GET` method,
so you need to check it after,

```
$('.logo img').load(function(){
  //your code
});
```

If you want your image gets loaded instantly you may go with BASE64 image.
For more detail  [Plase see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)

Answer (score 0):

it can be javascript modifying the layout of page, for example it can be script tags included on the bottom of the page, or any other javascript code executed on JQuery ready or load events. For example if this code appending html code it can affect width of you .logo div.

Another possibility is that your html is incorrect, to check this simply run any HTML validator like this http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html. When taking HTML from your page for validation, be aware that some browsers fix the incorrect HTML, so better get it from your source code.